# how to remove object from $scope. variable angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

How to remove one object from `$scope.Profile.address` object  please help me  see below code and image

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in Profile.addresses">
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault" ng-model='x.site_name ' name='site_name'></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault" ng-model='x.street_address ' name='street_address'></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault" ng-model='x.city ' name='city'></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault" ng-model='x.state ' name='state'></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault" ng-model='x.country ' name='country'></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault" ng-model='x.zip_code ' name='zip_code'></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault" ng-model='x.phone_number ' name='phone_number'></td>
    <td><a href="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove Address" ng-click="removeAddress(x.addresses)"><i class="fa fa-close text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
</tr>
```

JS

```
$scope.removeAddress = function(address) {

    var index = $scope.Profile.addresses.indexOf(address);

    if (index != -1)
      $scope.Profile.addresses.splice(index, 1);
    console.log($scope.Profile.addresses);
};
```

I have 3 objects and I want to remove one please help me
    [image]

Comment: so do u have any errors with your code? i think you are trying to remove dup's in your array

Comment: Did you tried with `delete  $scope.Profile.address` ?

Comment: i want delete one object from my array i am showing html

Comment: Use splice , myArray.splice(0, 1)

Comment: yes i was use but its not working

Comment: check the response of splice, are you getting the element deleted.. `var removed = arr.splice(index, 1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is working fine. You are missing something else in your code.
Make sure you are passing variables properly from UI.

```
  <ul ng-repeat="add in Profile.addresses">
    <li ng-click="removeAddress(add)">
      {{add.address}}:{{add.phone}}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Have a look here [Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/nTUOvyMHcDRdtSzyecLw?p=preview)

It should be ng-click=***"removeAddress(x)"*** not ng-click="removeAddress(x.addresses)"

change======================^

Answer (score 0):

Just for the heck of it, instead of splicing out the variable from the array, try creating and setting a new array.

So instead of the "find index then splice" in-place array edit, do something like this:

```
// newArray will contain all objects except the one you want removed
var newArray = $scope.profile.addresses.filter ( function ( d ) {
    return d.address !== address;
});

// newArray should trace out as you'd expect, unless filtering didn't find a match
console.log ( newArray );
// If all is well, replace the old array
$scope.profile.addresses = newArray;
// $scope.profile.addresses should be the same as newArray
console.log ( $scope.profile.addresses )
```

Now if THAT doesn't work, or it does work but the UI doesn't seem to be updating, then your problem might be applying scope ($scope.$apply()).